# Pole zero plot and frequancy response of a system in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, response, frequency, zero, magnitude

I have the following system:

[image]

I am required to find its frequency response using freqresp() function and find its magnitude response over the range  0 ≤ ω ≤ 20 in steps of 0.01. I am also required to plot its magnitude response and compare the results with its pole zero plot.
I wrote following code for this in matlab but don't know whats the problem with this. The code is running without error but I think the plot of magnitude response is wrong. Kindly help me about these questions.

```
w = 0:0.01:20;
num = [3 4]; 
den = [1 5 8 4]; 
zeros = roots(num);
poles = roots(den);
H = tf (num,den);
%pzmap(H)
%grid on
H1 = freqresp(H,w);
H2 = squeeze(H1);
plot(w,abs(H2))
xlabel('w');
ylabel('freq response');
```

Comment: "but I think the plot of magnitude response is wrong"
why do you think that? Do you have the expected response for the problem? your code seems fine

Comment: No, I don't have the expected response. As my frequency response is not relating pole zero plot that's why I am thinking that there is something wrong here and I don't what's that.

Comment: plot it with `semilogx`